# Node.js keep try to process command "find"

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemon

So, I have a problem with my node.js.
Somehow, when I'm running the server.js the processor got hot quickly.
So, I try to know why using "top" command.
The list showed that there are command "find" keep executed every several seconds. And it not just one... more than 10 and using the CPU more than 10%.

After that when I'm using command "cat /proc/"find_pid"/cmdline" 
I got this :
find -L/(-ipath/.git-prune-or-ipath/node_modules-prune-or-ipath/bower_components-prune-or-ipath/.sass-cache-prune)-or(-typef-and-mmin-10.316666666666666-print)

With different PID of other "find" command running, I got almost the same thing
except that the numbers before the -print is changed.

Anyone know what may caused this ?

Because, I'm totally blind about what happened here.

I'm running the server.js using nodemon.

Thank you before...

My code :

```
//create html
function createHTML (timestamp) {
  return    <html_body>
}

//ENDPOINTS

app.get ('/', function (req,res) {
  res.send (createHTML());
});

//execute shell script to trigger relay
function relayTrigger (num,status) {
 if (num != 8 ) exec <gpio_script>
 else if (num == 8 ) exec <gpio_script>
}

//for getting the status
app.get('/getRelay', function (req, res){
 date = new Date();
 dateString = date.toISOString();

 console.log('Get server: ' +
                       '                    '
                         + dateString);

 res.send (<status>);       
 res.end();
})

//For controlling the relay 
app.get ('/relayUpdate', function (req,res) {
 var on_button_snip = '';
 var off_button_snip = '';

 console.log ("Relay "+ req.query.relayNum + " is "+req.query.status); 
 //determine displayed button by parsing the status parameter
 if (req.query.status == "On") {
  on_button_snip = '<img src="public/ON_bright.PNG"         style="width:154px;height:99px">';
  off_button_snip = '<img src="public/OFF_dark.PNG" style="width:154px;height:99px">';
  } else {
  on_button_snip = '<img src="public/ON_dark.PNG" style="width:154px;height:99px">';
  off_button_snip = '<img src="public/OFF_bright.PNG" style="width:154px;height:99px">';
  }

  //determine which snippet needs to be updated by parsing the relayNum argument
  relay_number = parseInt (req.query.relayNum);
  switch (relay_number) {
  case 1:
   r1_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=1&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=1&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
   if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (97,"on");
      relay1status = "1";
   }
   else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (97,"off");
      relay1status = "0";
   }
   //console.log (r1_html_snip);
   break;
  case 2:
   r2_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=2&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=2&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
   if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (108,"on");
      relay2status = "1";
      }
   else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (108,"off");
      relay2status = "0";
   }
   //console.log (r2_html_snip);
   break;
case 3:
  r3_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=3&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=3&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (100,"on");
      relay3status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (100,"off");
      relay3status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r3_html_snip);
  break;
case 4:
  r4_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=4&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=4&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (101,"on");
      relay4status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (101,"off");
      relay4status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r4_html_snip);
  break;
case 5:
  r5_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=5&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=5&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (117,"on");
      relay5status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (117,"off");
      relay5status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r5_html_snip);
  break;
case 6:
  r6_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=6&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=6&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (105,"on");
      relay6status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (105,"off");
      relay6status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r6_html_snip);
  break;
case 7:
  r7_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=7&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=7&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (103,"on");
      relay7status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (103,"off");
      relay7status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r7_html_snip);
  break;
case 8:
  r8_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=8&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=8&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (106,"on");
      relay8status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (106,"off");
      relay8status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r8_html_snip);
  break;
case 9:
  r1_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=1&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=1&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r2_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=2&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=2&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r3_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=3&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=3&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r4_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=4&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=4&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r5_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=5&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=5&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r6_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=6&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=6&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r7_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=7&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=7&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r8_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=8&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=8&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>",
  r9_html_snip = "<table style='width:25%'><tr><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=9&status=On'>"+on_button_snip+"</a></td><td><a href='relayUpdate?relayNum=9&status=Off'>"+off_button_snip+"</a></td></tr></table>";
  if (req.query.status == "On") {
      relayTrigger (8,"on");
      relay9status = "1";
  }
  else if (req.query.status == "Off") {
      relayTrigger (8,"off");
      relay9status = "0";
  }
  //console.log (r9_html_snip);
  break;
  }
  res.redirect ("/");
  res.end();
 });

app.listen (port, function (err) {  
  console.log ('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Basically, I have 8 relay which I'll control from browser using html.
The button is just a picture which will change if the button is pushed.

Comment: this is a bit more suited to sys admin of stackexchangfe.. but can you show us your thread execution code ? or at least SOME of the code causing the over heat.. Otherwise we're all blindly answering! :)

Comment: Hi, I already add my code... The problem is I don't know which part that may cause this problem. Since I didn't use any "find" command inside the code. Is there any other possibility which may cause this problem ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119378/unknown-find-processes-running-in-ubuntu