# Unknown FIND processes running in UBUNTU

Tags: node.js, mongojs

I have been seeing tons of these FIND process. I am running **nodejs** with express and trying to poke the web service using POSTMAN. I have no clue what triggers these processes and this thing is slowing the server down.

While it does say something about node_modules, I have no idea what's going on. Note: I am using MongoDb with MongoJS plugin.

```
root     23597     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:10:03 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     23669     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:53 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     23723     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:43 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     23788     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:36 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     23846     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:28 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     23915     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:19 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     23988     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:10 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     24100     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:09:02 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
root     24284     1  0 Jun27 ?        00:08:52 find -L / ( -ipath /.git -prune -or -ipath /node_modules -prune -or
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason for this. Turns out NODEMON spawns all those find processes.

As per discussion on github, make the following changes to avoid nodemon trying to find the following directories:

nodemon/lib/config/defaults.js

```
ignore: ['.git/', 'node_modules/', 'bower_components/', '.sass-cache/'],
```